# MY CHEST IS UNEQUAL.Help me make them equal.please

Tags: exercise, muscle, training, recovery, technique

My chests are not equal.My left chest is fully outward and developed and where as my right is full pressed in.PLEASE help me to make both sides equal. this is affecting my abs to making them unequal.

Comment: Has it always been like that? How bad is the difference? Can you perhaps show an image to give us an idea of what do you mean by not equal. Without seeing - based on assumptions - all I can say is that it is probably genetic and not much you can do.

Comment: Among other things, you may want to have your spine examined by a doctor (not a chiropractor because they'll tell you that your spine is out of line and order multiple X-rays no matter what state it's in). Scoliosis can cause this sort of imbalance.

Comment: Consider providing some photos or measurements to help. If it is severe, see a doctor.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a lot of difference which can be noticed easily then you should definitely go to a doctor and let it be examined. If the difference is minor then it is quite normal because no one ever has an aesthetic and proportionate physique naturally. Even professional bodybuilders struggle a lot for perfect aesthetics. Normally, difference between some of body parts can be seen commonly, like size of right and left biceps,, size of left and right traps and chest too